# filter array of ojects with max value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I have an array of objects like below:

```
let tbrows =  [{"rowindx":0,"speciescnt":2},{"rowindx":0,"speciescnt":3},{"rowindx":1,"speciescnt":2},{"rowindx":1,"speciescnt":3}]
```

I want to get the maximum value of speciecnt for each row (i.e. after filtering the array) I would like it to be

```
let tbrows = [{"rowindx":0,"speciescnt":3},{"rowindx":1,"speciescnt":3}];
```

I am using the following code that I found on the web to filter an array but it only filters on one attribute of object.

```
const max2 = tbrows.reduce((op, item) => op = op > item.speciescnt? op : item.speciescnt, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also using `reduce()` to do it

```js
let tbrows =  [{"rowindx":0,"speciescnt":2},{"rowindx":0,"speciescnt":3},{"rowindx":1,"speciescnt":2},{"rowindx":1,"speciescnt":3}]

let result = tbrows.reduce((a,c) => {
  let obj = a.find(i => i.rowindx == c.rowindx)
  if(!obj){
    a.push(c)
  }else if(c.speciescnt > obj.speciescnt){
   obj.speciescnt = c.speciescnt
  }
  return a
},[])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the array into an object (right now, you're trying to turn it into just a number). Have the object be indexed by the row index, with the associated value for that row as the highest `speciecnt` found so far. Then you can turn the object back into an array.

```js
const input = [{"rowindx":0,"speciescnt":2},{"rowindx":0,"speciescnt":3},{"rowindx":1,"speciescnt":2},{"rowindx":1,"speciescnt":3}];

const grouped = {};
for (const { rowindx, speciescnt } of input) {
  grouped[rowindx] = Math.max(grouped[rowindx] ?? -Infinity, speciescnt);
}
const output = Object.entries(grouped)
  .map(([rowindx, speciescnt]) => ({ rowindx, speciescnt }));
console.log(output);
```